# Site Login Buttons Flicker between hover and normal states

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

There's some strange behaviour happening on the login screen.  When you hover over the very top edge of one of the login buttons, the button image flutters between the 'hover' and 'normal' states:

[image: Hover over the top edge of a login button to see some strange behaviour.]

Can anyone else reproduce this?  I'm using Google Chrome, at the moment.

Comment: Yes, I can reproduce it, the button moves a pixel or so as the border property changes on hover, which causes the button to "no longer be where the pointer is", and thus un-hover, causing you to be hovering over the button again.

Comment: I think this is working as intended. Since the idea is to have each type of login as an extruded button (at an angle, note the direction of the drop shadow). When you hover over it, the cursor presses it down. The other larger [Stack Exchange](http://stackoverflow.com/users/login) [sites](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/login) login pages are reflected in the same way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

This was addressed (albeit inadvertently) when the login screen was redesigned:

[image: New login screen]

Comment: After all these years!  Closure!

Comment: @GnomeSlice there's nothing quite like "we just removed it" as a fix for issues like this :)